# What exactly happens when i don't use "self" key while initialising a variable like m1 inside a class method. m1 is local,object or class variable?

Tags: python, oop

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,m1,m2):
        m1=m1
        m2=m2
        print(m1+m2)

s1=Student(10,20)
s2=Student(20,30)

print(Student.m1)
```

#i have just started the oops concepts so am a little confused now. when writing "print(Student.m1) or print(s1.m1)" am getting compile time error as
"AttributeError: type object 'Student' has no attribute 'm1'".

Comment: quick question - what you expect this `m1 = m1` to do really and why? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use `self`, you are just assigning the value to a local variable which cannot be accessed once the function has finished.

If you use `self.m1`, the value is assigned to an attribute of self, and can later be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the values as properties (via `self`), the names (`m1`, `m2`..) are lost when they go out of scope (when `__init__(...)` returns)

This is practically the same as using names inside a function - they only exist in that scope unless put somewhere else!